# Android LibVLC getBitmap from a TextureView

Tags: java, android, vlc, libvlc

I am trying to retrieve a frame from a video that is playing back using LibVLC in android. For reference, this is how I am starting LibVLC. ffmpegSv is a TextureView

```
public void startMediaPlayer() {
        ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<>();
        options.add("--no-drop-late-frames");
        options.add("--no-skip-frames");
        options.add("-vvv");
        options.add("--no-osd");
        options.add("--rtsp-tcp");
        options.add("--no-snapshot-preview");
        options.add("--no-video-title");
        options.add("--no-spu");
        videoVlc = new LibVLC(getActivity(), options);

        TextureView surfaceView = (TextureView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.streamView);

        newVideoMediaPlayer = new org.videolan.libvlc.MediaPlayer(videoVlc);
        final IVLCVout vOut = newVideoMediaPlayer.getVLCVout();
        vOut.setVideoSurface(ffmpegSv.getSurfaceTexture());
        vOut.setWindowSize(ffmpegSv.getWidth(), ffmpegSv.getHeight());
        vOut.attachViews();

        Media videoMedia = new Media (videoVlc, Uri.parse("rtsp://1.1.1.1/abc.mov"));
        newVideoMediaPlayer.setMedia(videoMedia);
        newVideoMediaPlayer.play();
    }
```

And this is how I am attempting to get the bitmap from it. I should note this method worked correctly when using the android MediaPlayer.

```
@Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        if (mStream != null) {
            if (idx++ % 10 == 0) {
                (new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        FileOutputStream out = null;
                        Bitmap b = ffmpegSv.getBitmap(ffmpegSv.getWidth(), ffmpegSv.getHeight());
                        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b2, 640, 480, true);
                        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bos);
                        byte[] arr = bos.toByteArray();
                        mStream.onJpegFrame(arr, 0L);
                        b.recycle();
                        bm.recycle();
                    }
                }).run();
                idx = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

However, the image that is being produced has a sliver of the original image from the TextureView around the edge almost like a border, but the rest of the image is obscured by a black box.

The only thing I can think of is that VLC uses some sort of overlay for subtitles etc that when pulled out with getBitmap() is losing its transparency. However, I am not 100% sure this is the case. Is there a way to check if this is the case, or disable any sort of overlays that VLC could be adding?

EDIT : I have added a sample image to demonstrate the problem:

[image]

You can just make out the bottom, right and top of the background image and a clear rectangle over the top of it.

Comment: Right now I have a similar issue, with `de.mrmaffen:libvlc-android:2.1.12@aar` never reached `onSurfaceTextureUpdated`. The events from player arrive, but the texture never are updated.

Comment: For me, this all worked fine when tested on Android 7. I have switched to using libvlc for android >= a and the stock MediaPlayer for 6 and below.

Comment: That should read >= 7

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap b = ffmpegSv.getBitmap(ffmpegSv.getWidth(), ffmpegSv.getHeight());
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b2, 640, 480, true);
```

Aren't you scaling something else here?
What is b2?